# PocoDynamo - How do I change the table name at runtime for Put and Delete

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, pocodynamo

I already have my tables created in DynamoDB, and I'd like to write to them using PocoDynamo. However, I need to change the table name at runtime based on the environment I'm running in. I can successfully do this when Querying like so:

```
    private string _environment = "dev";
    private IEnumerable<Television> Load()
    {
        var db = new PocoDynamo(_client);
        var q = db.FromQuery<Television>(q => q.Id == 1);
        Decorate(q, _environment);
        return q.Exec();
    }
    private void Decorate<TPoco>(QueryExpression<TPoco> query, string decorator)
    {
        query.TableName = $"{decorator}-{query.TableName}";
    }
```

This works great, but I can't see how to do this at runtime with Put and Delete.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to sort this out by altering the metadata in register:

```
var decorator = "production";
var db = new PocoDynamo(_client);
db.RegisterTable(typeof(Television));
var metaTableData = _pocoDb.GetTableMetadata(type);
metaTableData.Name = $"{decorator}-{metaTableData.Name}";
```

Then Put and Delete Work fine:

```
// the following will add/delete items with table name "production-Television"
db.PutItems(televisions);
db.DeleteItems<Television>(televisionHashes);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also add an alias attribute dynamically to the type.

ie.

```
entityType.AddAttributes(new AliasAttribute(alias));
db.RegisterTable(entityType);
```

AddAttributes comes from ServiceStack.Text PlatformExtensions